# MOTD: '444 updates can be applied immediately'. `apt list --upgradable` lists just 4!

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, updates, motd

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS machine that [says to me, after logging in:](https://pastebin.com/iA40kGnw)

> 444 updates can be applied immediately.
>
> To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable

But when I use `apt list --upgradable`, as suggested, it lists just 4 available updates.

- Why is the machine lying to me?

I don't remember doing anything that could possibly justify this passive-agressive behaviour towards me.

1. [The suggestion to logout and login again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339225/why-does-the-number-of-upgradable-packages-differ-according-to-motd-and-apt-list) is not fixing the MOTD;
2. [The suggestion to run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376929/motd-display-updates-can-be-applied-though-none-is-actually-available) `run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` does not fixes MOTD, as it just displays it again, and `cat /run/motd.dynamic.new` can't work because `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Previous discussion suggests that you seem to have a different problem with MOTD itself. Check your syslog for clues. I don't run 18.04 anymore, so will bow out.

Comment: @user535733 Maybe it could be caused by [this 'unmet dependencies' error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456349/unmet-dependencies-containerd-breaks-docker-io)?

Comment: @user535733 After fixing the 'unmet dependencies' error, the MOTD started to correctly show "0" instead of "444". As you helped a lot on solving the 'unmet dependencies' error, would you like to formally provide the answer to the original question here?

Comment: Fee free to detail the solution. You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that one update was stuck, giving this error:

> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

[After the unmet dependency was solved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456349/unmet-dependencies-containerd-breaks-docker-io), `apt upgrade` resumed working, and MOTD automatically started to get updated with the correct number of available updates.